# "which" with non-noun-phrase antecedent

Tags: grammar

I became a little unsure regarding to grammar while writing a sentence that, "... will either pass through the top-right or bottom-left corner, during which ...", in which case "which" has an implied antecedent of "passing through". I believe this sentence is clear enough, but wonder whether such usage of "which" may be disapproved in formal or academic writing.

*more examples:*
"He resigned that post, after which he engaged in ranching."
"He died of cancer, which is what I predicted"

Comment: In your examples, *which* references something like *the fact of the preceding statement being true*, or *the thing described by the preceding statement*. It's perfectly normal English, and there's no suggestion it's in any way "loose" or "improper". You're just being misled by simplistic usage descriptions suggesting that *which* always references ***ordinary nouns***, just because that's the simplest and most common case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you think *during which time* might be slightly better?

Comment: @Araucaria: We don't have the full context of an actual sentence within which OP's fragment might occur, ***which*** might affect any preference. If I'd wanted to, I could have introduced an explicit noun there *(...which **lack** might affect things)*, but I don't see why that would be "better". By the same token, OP could introduce, say, ***time*** or ***passage*** - both perfectly possible, but they're just (very slightly stilted, IMHO) stylistic variations, not really "improvements" in any objective sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, use two sentences; figuring out the geometry has used up this one.

- *.. will pass through either the top-right or the bottom-left corner. During this transition, ...*
  (also, move *either* closer to the disjunction, and repeat the article to clarify it)

"Such usage of *which*" is not "frowned on"; but it does require a lot of interpretation by the reader.
What passes for good writing mostly is just not loading too much information into one sentence.
I.e, this is not a grammatical problem -- the relative clause is well-formed -- but a writing problem.

As can be seen in the other two examples

- *He resigned that post, after which he engaged in ranching.*
- *He died of cancer, which is what I predicted.*

a relative clause referring to a prior clause is perfectly grammatical.  Even a preferred choice, **provided** one doesn't expect a simple structure to do all the heavy lifting involved in description.

Answer (score -1):

The first example looks fine to me, though a clearer alternative may be:

> He resigned his post, then engaged in ranching.

or

> He resigned his post, before taking up ranching.

---

In the second example, the following reads better:

> He died of cancer, as I had predicted.

replacing the "which" and changing the tense of your historical prediction.