# ‘Which’ Referring To A Whole Clause

Tags: clauses

I know some relative clauses refer to a whole clause.

My example:

> She just thought that I was proud and stuck-up which I won’t defend myself.

Is it right to say "which" can refer to the whole of the previous clause here ?

Comment: Well, no, not in that sentence. _I won't defend myself_ is a complete sentence all by itself and has no room for _which_, nor for the clause it's supposed to represent. So it can't be a relative clause. However, if you said _which is not true_ or _which I don't believe_ instead, it would be perfectly grammatical, since _which_ could be a part of the relative clause.

Comment: @John Lawler. (1) If not a relative clause, what kind of clause is it? (If we had to give it a name). (2) And what is its function? (Maybe just "modifier" and leave it at that?) Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Which' with non-noun-phrase antecedent](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198442/which-with-non-noun-phrase-antecedent)

Comment: I take your meaning to be  'She just thought that I was proud and stuck-up, which accusation I won’t defend myself.' / 'She just thought that I was proud and stuck-up, which accusation I won’t myself defend.' Very garden-pathy.

Comment: The example is difficult to parse, @Puzzled.  John seems to think that "myself" only works as the object of "defend", leaving no role for the "which" to fulfill within its own clause -- which I wouldn't assume myself.  Martin's intent might have been to use the reflexive form as an intensifier.  That would allow the "which" to serve as direct object -- that opinion which he himself won't defend.  Until Martin explains what the clause is intended to mean, we simply aren't in a good position to judge it, let alone correct it.

Comment: Absent context, I think the problems are (i) the "myself" - it can be omitted, (ii) the verb *defend* and (iii) the lack of a comma: *She just thought that I was proud and stuck-up, which I will not defend.* or *She just thought that I was proud and stuck-up, which I will not respond to.*

Comment: Aha, I heard the sentence wrong. It would be said differently if it were not reflexive _defend_, but I didn't hear that one. Every written sentence is multiply ambiguous that way, which is why linguists are (sposta be) careful about picking their examples. As for the sense that I missed, if _which_ is the object of _defend_, then **Yes!** it can refer to the whole clause. I mean, how else would you refer to it? But there would hafta be comma intonation because it's a non-restrictive clause, and that was missing, another problem hearing the example.